# Does PHP for Windows work with VC10 (Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1)?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, windows-7, php5

My system is Windows 7 x86. Im going to install Apache 2.4.2 VC10 from [Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) and it requires Visual C++ 2010:

> Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ 2010 SP1
>   Redistributable Package x86.

While PHP 5.4.4 VC9 x86 Thread Safe (as stated on [PHP for Windows](http://windows.php.net/) page) requires Visual C++ 2008:

> The VC9 versions require you to have the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime
>   (x86)  or the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x64) installed.

Seems i have to install both. Can PHP work **only with Visual C++ 2010 SP1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are referring to (Apache Lounge) **clearly says that it will work**:

> Note: a VC10 binary loads VC10 and VC9 modules.

...

> Works with the PHP 5.4, 5.3 and 5.2 handlers (php5apache2_4.dll) below **and the binaries from windows.php.net**

Answer (score 0):

As opposite to what ApacheLounge tells, it seems necessary to install both Visual C++ 2008 SP1 (for PHP VC9) and Visual C++ 2010 SP1 (For Apache VC10).

Then, it works like a charm, but without doing this, there is a 'side-by-side' problem loading the PHP module.
But I admit I wonder if it would not just be better to run all 'suite' using VC9, instead of mixing VC9/VC10.

Comment: Because Apache Lounge does not seem to provide a VC9 version of FastCGI